# My partitions are not shown since I installed Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, 14.04, system-installation, data-recovery

I had Windows 8.1 installed in my system and I had 3 partitions in it.

I installed Ubuntu 14.4 with the **Replace Windows 8.1** option.

After installing Ubuntu I had only one partition.

Have all my partitions been erased? If so how can I recover my data?

Answer (score 0):

If you installed Ubuntu 14.04 with the replace Windows 8.1 option then it replaced Windows 8.1 completely which means that Ubuntu took over the partitions that used to be occupied by Windows 8.1.

Even though the partition has been "deleted" the data should still be there as long as it was not overwritten by new files.

You may still be able to recover some of the data from the Windows 8.1 partition using some of the tools in this documentation. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DataRecovery

Keep in mind you may not be able to recover all of your files, and some of the files that you do recover may be corrupted.